# Python command line program: generate man page from existing documentation and include in the distribution

Tags: python, python-sphinx, distutils

Following an (hopefully) common practice, I have a Python package that includes several modules and an executable script in a separate `scripts` directory, as can be seen [here](http://bitbucket.org/steko/totalopenstation/src).

The documentation for the script, apart from the auto-generated help given by optparse, is together with the package documentation in a Sphinx subdirectory. I am trying to:

1. generate the man page for the script from the existing documentation
2. include the man page in the distribution

I can easily do #1 with Sphinx, the `man_pages` setting and `sphinx-build -b man`. So I can call `python setup.py build_sphinx -b man` and have the man page generated in the `build/sphinx/man` directory.

Now I would like to be able to have the generated man page included in the distribution tarball, so GNU/Linux packagers can find it and install it to the proper location. Various options like `package_data` do not seem to work here because the man page is not there until it is generated by Sphinx. This could also apply to i18n files (`.mo` vs `.po` files).

Including files that are not part of the source in `MANIFEST.in` doesn't seem right. The possibility of commiting the generated files to the source repository looks like an awful thing to do and I would like to avoid it.

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

To add static man pages in you distribution, you can add them in the `MANIFEST` file.

```
recursive-include docs *.txt
recursive-include po *.po
recursive-include sample_data *
recursive-include data *.desktop *.svg *.png
include COPYING.txt
include README.txt
recursive-include man_pages
```

Where `man_pages` is the directory containing the copies of generated man pages.

See also: http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/man.1.php

Comment: Thanks Laurent, the question is more about programmatically generating man pages when building the Python source distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that I have seen done before is to provide a build target for your docs and make it clear in the README file that the documentation includes man pages and can be built by running that build target.  Package maintainers then build your docs and package them during the package creation process.

The fedora 18 rpm for [hawkey](https://github.com/akozumpl/hawkey), for example, builds this way.  I have also seen other rpms follow the model of building documentation at the same time as the source is built, then packaging it.

Comment: Do you mean a build target for make/cmake?

Answer (score 1):

I would cause  setup.py to generate the man pages probably before calling distutils.core.setup.  Remember that setup.py at one level is python code.  You want to test and make sure that it works even if  sphinx is not installed (unless you require sphinx).  So, if the man pages already exist and sphinx is not available do not fail.  That way someone who unpacks your source distribution without sphinx can still run setup.py build and other targets.

The other option is to check in the man pages, but like you, I find that ugly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting with "make sure the man pages exist when python setup.py is run"

Comment: Sorry, that was kind of ambiguous unless you live in my head.  I've tried to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This question deserve a better answer, and not only because this issue has been bothering me for a while. So here is my implementation.

- Download `build_manpage.py` from my github project (here is [a link to build_manpage](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pwman3/pwman3/d718a01fa8038893e42416b59cdfcda3935fe878/build_manpage.py))
- Save it somewhere you can import it to your setup.py

  ```
  # inside setup.py
  from setuptools import setup
  from build_manpage import BuildManPage

  ...
  ...

  setup(
  ...
  ...
  cmdclass={
  'build_manpage': BuildManPage,
  )
  ```

Now you can invoke `setup.py` like this:

```
$ python setup.py build_manpage --output=prog.1 --parser=yourmodule:argparser
```

Comment: As of 2015-01-17, the “link to build_manpage” returns a 404 Not Found error. Can you package this and publish on PyPI? Or, even better, work with the Setuptools folks to get it incorporated in a new version?

Comment: @bignose, I stated working on this: https://github.com/oz123/man-utils. But I lack the time to finish the work. I also wrote to the setuptools mailing list but no one seemed interested, so I didn't follow further.. If you look at the setup.py of you will find the content of build_manpage.